# How Can I Remove the DependsOnMethods in @Test during runtime

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I have a Question regarding DependsOnMethods!

Scenario:

TestFile

```
@Test
public void test1(){
System.out.println("My First Test");
}

@Test (dependsOnMethods = "test1")
public void test2() {
System.out.println("My Second Test");
}
```

Now when Executing First Time, test1 -> Pass, test2 -> Fail

Note: Test Results are saved in DB.

On Reexecuting the same test, I want to execute only test2 (not test1)
But TestNG will execute both Test1 and Test2 since both are dependent.

I have tried using IAnnotationTransformer, transform method like

```
@Override
public void transform(ITestAnnotation annotation, Class testClass, Constructor testConstructor, Method testMethod) {
String result = //get Status of test based on testNo from db
if (result.equals("Fail")) {
annotation.setDependsOnMethods(new String[]{});
}
```

But this didn't work, it was again executed from Test1.
Is there any other solution to approach this problem?

Comment: Have you mentioned the annotation transformer in suite xml?

Comment: Yes, Added in-suite XML.

Comment: Have you checked if `annotation.setDependsOnMethods(new String[]{});` statement is getting executed?

Comment: Yes, I have tried to print the Depends on method using annotation.getDependsOnMethods() it displayed as Empty.